# How to Setup Static IP

Tags: pi-3, networking, static-ip

I'm trying to follow instructions on how to properly setup a static ip on the eth0 for my Pi running ubuntu server 16

i altered the dhcpcd.conf and added a .cfg in the interfaces.d directory to have a static ip of 192.168.1.257( outside the router pool) but on doing a `ifconfig -a` I get

> inet address 192.168.1.75 Bcast 192.168.1.257

the .75 is the old ip assigned dynamically by the router and .257 the static ip is what is being broadcast

I'm trying to `ifdown eth0 and ifup eth0` but keep getting a response

> RNETLINK answerers: File exists Failed to bring up eth0

I'm able to ping the .257 address but can't access services like ssh and http

the goal is to be able to connect to the pi over the internet. What steps have i missed here?

Comment: You **CANNOT** have an ip address `192.168.1.257` because this is nonsense; the maximum value for each octet is 255. If you want help you need to describe what you have actually configured. AFAIK Ubuntu **DOES NOT** use `dhcpcd`, although I guess it can be setup if you try hard enough.

Comment: @Milliways sorry for that. I thought when you setup static ip address they should not be in the range of route pool ip addresses. I wasn't to be able to access my pi remotely( and possibly switch OS on the fly) and saw that it can be done by using NO-IP with port forwarding.